# Trigger macro with change in different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies any incorrect terms, this is the first time I am trying to code a macro.  I currently have the following code running:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
'Alpha Show / Hide
If Sheets("Project_selection").Range("D4") = Range("C2") Then
    Sheet3.EnableCalculation = True
ElseIf Sheets("Project_selection").Range("D4") = "All" Then
    Sheet3.EnableCalculation = True
    Else
        Sheet3.EnableCalculation = False
End If
End Sub
```

which has been cobbled together from other codes and google.  It works, but only when I move out of the sheet, which I think is being driven by the first line.

I would actually like it to activate when the Cell D4 in the 'Project_selection' sheet (a separate sheet to the one the code is on) gets changed - does anyone know how I would do that?  I have seen references to worksheet_change, but I do not understand how one defines the target/range to get the appropriate reference.

Hope that makes sense and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you were to place the following code under the sheet (Project_selection), it would fire that event every time a change has happened in Cell D4:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Project_selection")
    If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then
        If ws.Range("D4") = ws.Range("C2") Then
            Sheet3.EnableCalculation = True
        ElseIf ws.Range("D4") = "All" Then
            Sheet3.EnableCalculation = True
        Else
            Sheet3.EnableCalculation = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  However, am I right that if I wanted to add a new sheet with the same result (sheet 4 say) that I would then need to add to this Macro?  If so, the problem is that others will be using this who do not use macros at all and therefore would not be able to update.   That's why I was hoping to have a macro assigned to each tab that, when copied, would maintain the code.

Comment: @Padlilly115 what you could do, is add this code and amend it slightly to the Workbook, so when the change happens in a given cell in any of your sheets, it would run, but it would depend on how many sheets you want to omit and include.

Comment: that is actually a very simple but brilliant idea, I'll see if I can get that working.  Thanks very much for your help.